# Specify version when creating a aws-sdk-php client

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-4, amazon-s3

I'm using [Laravel Stapler](https://github.com/CodeSleeve/laravel-stapler) to save model attachments to s3. Reading through the docs I came up with the following code and stuck it in the model's save method.

```
        $this->hasAttachedFile('recording', [
            'url' => '/recording/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename',
            'storage' => 's3',
            's3_client_config' => [
                'key' => 'accessKey',
                'secret' => 'secretKey',
                'region' => 'us-east-1'
            ],
            's3_object_config' => [
                'Bucket' => 'bucket.aws.com'
            ],
        ]);
```

When I `find()` a model, set the attachment, and run `save()` I get:

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'version is a required configuration setting when creating a client.' in /Users/myName/Code/projectName/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Common/ClientFactory.php:99`

The ClientFactory `create()` method required a 'version' to be set. Looking through the laravel-stapler and stapler docs I don't see anything mentioning a version. I'm using the most recent version of laravel-stapler with laravel 4.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Even though it wasn't in the docs I had to actually add a version when configuring s3.

```
       's3_client_config' => [
            'key' => 'accessKey',
            'secret' => 'secretKey',
            'region' => 'us-east-1',
            'version' => 'latest',
        ],
```